# Handling backgournd of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: pic]

Hi, In the pic above the arrow shaped image is background of textview. While the background of whole layout is done using shape.But I want that the arrow point should come out as in below pic. 
Can anybody help me in this.

[image: pic2]

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/timestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#808080"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    />


  <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/xyz"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firsttv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sectv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"

     />
 </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show some code you use to generate this?

Comment: Add `android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"`to your btn view. Change the value until you get the desired effect

Comment: No It is moving button out of the layout i.e cropping it. :(

Comment: Well..Then add the same margin to the layout, but the absolute value. i.e if you set -25dp as marginLeft to the button, set a 25dp marginLeft to its parent layout

Comment: I have now given full code of xml... 
This bubble thing is inside second relativelayout. 

Now tell what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you're trying to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firsttv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sectv"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sectv"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Button"
              android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
              android:paddingRight="15dp"
              android:paddingLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout"
              android:background="@drawable/xyz"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that the button must be outside of that relativelayout otherwise it will be croped